# How to execute service/activity in background from "Share" option?

Tags: android, service, share

We have an android app which does not appear in the menu and the only way to open it is when "sharing" a resource.
I need to execute the service which sends the resource without "seeing it", and when it finishes close the app, so the user keeps navegating wherever he is.
How to achieve this?

PD: Another valid solution would be to open a dialog with a progress bar and then close it. Anyway I don't find the solution for neither of that

Comment: Please check my answer and reply if you still face the issue. I am expecting a reply from your side.

Comment: @SunSun I am testing it. I had the code to send image and working fine in MainActivity, but here it seems to stop work. Any hint?

Comment: I don't have any idea. Did you find any new crash or error logs? Please share more details, then only I can able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Possible.

**Hiding App from the launcher menu:**
Create an app without a launcher activity. That is, there shouldn't be any activity declared in the manifest with the following filters.

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

You might face an issue on running such an app on device/emulator, you can solve that by changing the run configuration. This post will help you in such case - https://github.com/android/input-samples/issues/18

**Creating Dialog for Sharing Image:**
 Create Image handling activity with Dialog theme

Manifest code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name=".ImageSharingActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ShareAppTheme">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Style.xml code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

 <!-- Dialog theme for sharing activity -->
<style name="ShareAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
</style>
```

You can handle your sharing logic on ImageSharingActivity.